# Message Connect - Service broker error: Error 502

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to launch a Message Connect Service.

I selected the message connect from experiment service catalog and then click create.

After waiting for a short moment, Bluemix returned a message indicating

> Service broker error: {"description"=>"Error 502 received from broker url https://mcbroker-mcprod.ng.bluemix.net/v2/service_instances/5530bb71-179e-4508-8c0d-7ac9104f6f7c"}

Can someone please help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try now - looks like you tried to provision the service when it was experiencing an outage.

You can check the current provisioning status of Message Connect and other services on the [Bluemix Status page](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/status/)